# How to convert numpy array to batches while feeding tensorflow session for training

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network

The dataset is large how to use feed data using a batch size of 100. 
`x_u is image data and y_u is labels
    x_u, y_u are of sizes 2000000
    with tf.Session() as sess:
    #writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("output", sess.graph)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(3):
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: x_u, y_: y_u, keep_prob: 1.0})
        print('step %d, training accuracy: %g',  (i, train_accuracy))
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: x_u, y_: y_u, keep_prob:0.5})`

Answer (score 0):

```
BATCH_SIZE = 100
for offset in range(0, len(y_u), BATCH_SIZE):
    batch_x = x_u[offset: offset + BATCH_SIZE]
    batch_y = y_u[offset: offset + BATCH_SIZE]

    # Feed batch_x an batch_y
```